# Как подключиться в Linux к SMB 1.0?

Tags: linux

```
elena@elenaPC:~$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=elena //192.168.0.200/srv /mnt
Password for elena@//192.168.0.200/srv:  *******                       
mount error: Server abruptly closed the connection.
This can happen if the server does not support the SMB version you are trying to use.
The default SMB version recently changed from SMB1 to SMB2.1 and above. Try mounting with vers=1.0.
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

elena@elenaPC:~$ sudo mount -t cifs vers=1.0 -o username=elena //192.168.0.200/srv /mnt
mount: bad usage
Try 'mount --help' for more information.
```

Пытаюсь включить smb 1.0, но пишет ошибку.  Lubuntu

Comment: `mount -t cifs -o vers=1.0,username=elena ...`